# How to use literals to show youtube vidoes in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am working on a asp.net project and i want to be able to play i youtube video using

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="real_src">
</iframe>
```

where the src is replaced by the real src but when i do it and use inspect elemt to see the the value that was entered i get the following result

[image]
can someone explain me what is going on and how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a = sign after your src attribute.